# How do I figure the I2C timings for a peripheral?

Tags: i2c

The I2C timing specs are confusing me a bit. Here's a few timing characteristics from my peripheral :

[image]

It's basically the same as I2C timing specs provided by NXP. I am looking at specs at 100khz mode. The max rise and fall times for example are given, but not the minimum. Should I program my I2C controller on MCU for 1000 ns rise time only or could I go lower?

Similarly the specs for,say, START condition Hold time is given by a minimum 4 us. The max value is left as blank.

Do I go just by min and max values? Or if I can program differently, how high/low can I go?

Comment: what would be bad about lower rise times?

Comment: @MarcusMüller that's why I asked how high/low can I go? Could I go for,say, 10ns rise time? Or go like 100us hold time for START condition?

Comment: Which MCU is this? Usually the timing parameters of the bus are not given to the MCU, but there are exceptions.

Comment: @Justme this snap is from datasheet of port expander I am using. Not the MCU

Comment: @Luffy I understood that, but I asked which MCU you are using where the timing is programmable. I can give a better answer when I know how the MCU works.

Answer (score 4):

This is not something you'd typically need to adjust away from defaults.

In ordinary open-drain operation rise time would be governed by the pullup resistor chosen and bus capacitance.  You basically would not be able to make it "too fast" without requiring excessive drive down current, so really would just need to check that the rise time isn't approaching the maximum.  If it is you may need smaller resistors, within reason.  Should you find you need to a pullup firmer than say 2K2 to get a reasonable rise time, you probably have something wrong with the bus - often you can use at least twice that resistance if not more.

The fall time would depend on the strength of the drive, and is limited by physics.  Trying to achieve very short fall times is both pointless given the slow clock speed to be used, and perhaps counterproductive as hard edges could lead to the device being a source of radio interference extending to higher frequencies.

Answer (score 3):

If minimum values are not given then you should assume that the rise times can be zero. I would use the smallest rise time that my system could produce, which is likely limited by the resistor pullup and wiring capacitance.

Likewise, you will usually only see a minimum limit on hold time or clock high time because any value larger than that is guaranteed to work.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the MCU (STM32?) has programmable timings in order to allow setting the I2C mode (speed grade) simply by setting the correct timing parameters.

The 100kHz standard has no minimum rise time specified, so it could in theory be infinitely fast. However, all chips adhering to 100 kHz standard must allow for the maximum rise time, and thus the timings must be based on that, so that the minimum specified high time is still satisfied. It is safe to put 1000ns there. However, as all timings are programmable, and you know if you have a bus with fast rise time, feel free to set it lower. If you know you have a non-standard bus with 2000ns rise time, then you should use that value so clock high time is still within specs.

So by default, put the standard values for a given speed grade there. If you know something about the bus and all the components you can fine tune the values.

The MCU can't affect the rise and fall times, but it can just be set to be aware of them, so the fastest speed can be obtained.

Some parameters are left without min or max because some delays like the start hold time can be infinitely long if you want, but it must be 4us or more, or long enough so all chips recognize it, even the slowest ones. The rise and fall times being 0 or infinitely fast is also acceptable, but not achievable in practice, it just means it can be as fast as reasonably possible as long as it is not too slow. The faster standards do limit the slew rate so it must be slow enough that it will not cause much EMI.